# Why I am getting errors -Permisssion denied for firefox and unknown error: DevToolsActivePort FOR chrome?

Tags: permissions, firefox, google-chrome, python3, selenium

I am trying to setup google chrome, firefox along with selenium webdriver for webs scraping.
Tools version-

- Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
- Mozilla Firefox 87.0
- geckodriver 0.29.0 (cf6956a5ec8e 2021-01-14 10:31 +0200)
- ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294})
- python 3.8

Tools dir

- usr/bin/google-chrome
- usr/bin/firefox
- /usr/bin/geckodriver
- usr/local/bin/chromedriver

Error response for firefox setup

```
[Mon Apr 05 12:00:41.455935 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 166126:tid 140071119365888] [client 27.60.45.7:39715]     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,, referer: http://example.com/scrapfbmoz
[Mon Apr 05 12:00:41.455941 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 166126:tid 140071119365888] [client 27.60.45.7:39715]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child, referer: http://example.com/scrapfbmoz
[Mon Apr 05 12:00:41.455944 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 166126:tid 140071119365888] [client 27.60.45.7:39715]     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename), referer: http://example.com/scrapfbmoz
[Mon Apr 05 12:00:41.455964 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 166126:tid 140071119365888] [client 27.60.45.7:39715] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/firefox', referer: http://example.com/scrapfbmoz
```

Error response for chrome setup

```
[Mon Apr 05 10:30:31.315019 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 161147:tid 140070870828800] [client 106.205.46.151:9653] selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally., referer: http://example.com/scrapfb
[Mon Apr 05 10:30:31.315023 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 161147:tid 140070870828800] [client 106.205.46.151:9653]   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist), referer: http://example.com/scrapfb
[Mon Apr 05 10:30:31.315027 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 161147:tid 140070870828800] [client 106.205.46.151:9653]   (The process started from chrome location usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.), referer:
```

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer your question rather than asking you how this relates to Ubuntu:

For your Firefox issue, the error says: `PermissionDenied: /usr/local/bin/firefox`. This means whatever user this process is running under, you do not have the correct permissions for whatever it wants to do inside this directory. To resolve this, you have two options: you can run the process as root or elevated privileges (preferably sudo, not just signing into the root account) or you can change the permissions on the directory or ELF it is pointing to with `chmod` or `chown`. Please do note if you follow this, you will need `sudo`. `sudo chmod -R 644 /usr/local/bin/firefox`, `sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin/firefox` or `sudo chown <whatever user you want> -R /usr/local/bin/firefox` will work.

644: Owner can read and write, everyone else can just read.
755: Owner can read, write and execute, but everyone else can read and execute.

Please do correct me if I made a mistake anywhere!

As to your Selenium problem, that seems to be a very common issue. I would recommend upgrading your Chrome, webdriver and anything else to rule these out. There is a similar question on StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: There be dragons when running processes as root https://bencane.com/2012/02/20/why-you-should-avoid-running-applications-as-root/

Comment: @24601 I am aware, but instead of just posting a link and a caption, you could at least suggest a good alternative. I also did include a *somewhat better* option alongside the root option :)